# How to remove property when window size is scaled to lower or higher

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a table component here from antd
`<Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} scroll={{ x:1000 }} pagination={{pageSize: 4}} />`

Basically I wanted to remove the `scroll={{ x:1000 }}` when I make the browser window bigger, say than `1200px`. How can I achieve this in React?

**Booking function()**

```
function booking() {

    return (

        <div className="booking"> 
            <Navbar bg="" variant="dark" id="mainHeader">
                <Nav className="mr-auto">
                    <img
                        src={logo}
                        width="110"
                        height="50"
                        className="d-inline-block align-top ml-4 mt-3 mb-2"
                        alt="logo"
                    />
                </Nav>
                <Nav.Link a href="/" className="ml-sm-4 text-dark">Home</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link a href="/bookings" className=" text-dark">Bookings</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link a href="/signout" className="mr-sm-4 text-dark">Sign Out</Nav.Link>
            </Navbar>

            {/* My Booking Table */}
            <header className="App-header text-dark">
                    <Card border="light" className="bookingCard" id="bookingCard" >
                        <h1 className="mt-4 ml-4" id="cardTitle">Upcoming Bookings</h1>
                        <Card.Body>
                            <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} {...!!this.state.scroll && { scroll: { x: 1000 }}} pagination={{ pageSize: 4 }} />
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I wanted to change the Table there.

Comment: what about controlling the table width with media query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an event that fires on window resize. Small sample code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      resized: window.innerWidth < 1200
    };
    this.onResize = this.onResize.bind(this);
  }


  onResize() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 1200) {
      this.setState({ resized: true });
    } else {
      this.setState({ resized: false });
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.onResize);
  }
}
```

And in return statement:

```
<Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} scroll={{x: this.state.resized ?  1000 : 0}} pagination={{ pageSize: 4 }} />
```

Comment: I added the event inside the function and it says `TypeError: Cannot set property 'state' of undefined`

Comment: I think theres an error with the parsing for `Table`

Comment: @rwd I don't know what Table component you are using. Try something like:
<Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} scroll={{x: this.state.resized ?  1000 : 0}} pagination={{ pageSize: 4 }} />. The main thing for you is to understand the logic behind this.

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'state' of undefined` the error im getting. I placed the event inside the `booking()` function before the return statement is that fine?

Comment: @rwd , "Cannot set property 'state' of undefined" means that you don't have a React component. Because "this" in "this.state" means component. Try to duplicate the code from an answer, as it contains a properly defined component 
**export default class App extends React.Component {...}**